# When a Radon measure finite in bounded sets?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a locally compact separable complete metric space (locally compact Polish metric space) and $\sigma$ a Radon measure i.e. a Borel measure finite in compact sets $\sigma(K)<\infty$ and regular: For every $A \in \mathcal{B}(X)$
$$\sigma(A)=\inf\{ \sigma(O): A \subset O \text{ open} \},$$
$$\sigma(A)=\sup\{ \sigma(K): A \supset K \text{ compact} \}$$
Can I guarantee in this case that $\sigma$ is finite in bounded sets? They are bounded w.r.t. the distance $d$.

I know that this is true in $\mathbb{R}^d$ because closed balls are compact. In a metric space I can't use this fact. I proved that $\sigma$ is $\sigma$-finite because I can get a increasing sequence of compact $K_n$ such that $X = \cup_{n \geq 1} K_n$. Could you give me any hint? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every metric $d(x, y)$ you can define $\bar{d}(x, y)=min\{d(x, y), 1\}$ that is a metric inducing the same topology of $d(x, y)$ for wich every set is bounded. Hence I say no, elsewhere every set would have a finite measure.

Comment: With this in mind, do you know if I can get another equivalent metric where it is possible? i.e. a set is bounded if and only if it is compact? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In a metric space a set is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. In a complete metric space a set is compact if and only if it is closed and totally bounded. Hence your are looking for a metric such that bounded means totally bounded. In general totally boundness is a stronger condition, there are spaces of functions where only variant of uniform metric can be defined.But if you consider only space of continuous or bounded functions, under mild conditions, you can define the sup metric for wich could be the case.Take a look at ch. 7(spaces of functions) Munkers' "Topology"

Answer (score 2):

To add to Giovanni Barbarani's answer. If you use the $\overline{d}$ metric, then the space $X$ is bounded. So in order for $\sigma$ to be finite on bounded sets, you would need that $\sigma(X)<\infty$.

With this in mind, you need to add the constraint that $\sigma(X)<\infty$ or that your space has the Heine-Borel Property for every bounded set to have finite measure.

Comment: I think that another way to say that, following Munkres ch. 7, is that every bounded set must be totally bounded.

Comment: Hadn't heard of that word but that fits the bill

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail, it was very helpful.

Comment: Do you know if I can get another equivalent metric where it is possible? i.e. a set is bounded if and only if it is compact?